# Is $y^2 i − z^2 j + x^2 k$ conservative vector field?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis

I want to prove if $y^2 i − z^2 j + x^2k$ is a  conservative vector field. Is it sufficient to say that it is 'simply connected', and show that the curl is $0$? Or do I need to prove it by attempting to find a potential function?

Comment: How about showing its curl is non-zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our vector field is
$$\mathbf{F}(x,y,z)=y^2\hat{\mathbf{i}}-z^2\hat{\mathbf{j}}+x^2\hat{\mathbf{k}}$$
It is *conservative* if $\nabla \times\mathbf{F}=0~~\forall (x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3$.
So you need to check if
$$\nabla \times \mathbf{F}=\det\left(\begin{bmatrix}
\hat{\mathbf{i}} & \hat{\mathbf{j}} & \hat{\mathbf{k}}\\
\frac{\partial }{\partial x} & \frac{\partial }{\partial y} & \frac{\partial }{\partial z}\\
y^{2} & -z^{2} & x^{2}
\end{bmatrix}\right)=0$$
Which is in fact not the case.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple example where by trying to find a potencial function you would obtain the answer. An alternative could be the following- any open ball in the neighbourhood of $(0,0,0)$ is a convex set and then if it was a conservative field it would satisfy $\frac{\partial F_{i}}{\partial x_{j}}=\frac{\partial F_{j}}{\partial x_{i}} $ for $i,j=1,2,3$ which is not the case.